# Scanf doesnt take more than 4 characters in a const char array - C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, constants

I have a really weird bug. If I write a name which contains more than 4 characters, the printf will only output the first 4 characters.

Important note: I am **not allowed** to use *any other library than stdio.h* and I am **not allowed** to use *anything else than scanf for input and printf for output*. Moreover I am not allowed to modify the paramater list of the functions and I **have to use** *const char*. The code runs on putty via ssh on a unix system.

My code and the input/output are below. In addition, the while loop has a bug too ._.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int searchCharacters(const char*, char);
int getLength(const char*);

int main() {

    char yesNo;
    int end = 0;
    const char name[] = {""};

    printf("please enter a name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    int length = getLength(name);
    printf("\n%s has a length of %i", name, length);
    fflush(stdin);

    while(end != 1) {
        printf("\n\nWould you like to search a character in %s (y / n)?", name);
        scanf(" %c", &yesNo);

        switch(yesNo) {
            case 'y':
                printf("\nPlease enter a character: ");
                char searchingCharacter;
                scanf("%c", &searchingCharacter);
                int numberOfCharacters = searchCharacter(name, searchingCharacter);
                printf("\nThe letter %c is %i-times", searchingCharacter, numberOfCharacters);
                break;
            case 'n':
                printf("\nGood bye!");
                end++;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int searchCharacter(const char s[], char c) {
    int numberOfIterations = getLength(s);
    int numberOfCharacters = 0;
    int i;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) {
        if (s[i] == c) {
            numberOfCharacters++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfCharacters;
}

int getLength(const char s[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i++]);

    return (i - 1);
}
```

```
Input/Output:
    please enter a name: abcdefg

    abcd has a length of 7 characters.

    Would you like to search a character in abcd (y / n)? y

<-------------- AUTOMATIC/BUG WHILE LOOP --------------------------->

    Please enter a character:
    The letter
      is 0-times.

</--------------AUTOMATIC/BUG WHILE LOOP---------------------------->

    Would you like to search a character in abcd (y / n)? n

    Good bye!
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &yesNo);` --> `scanf(" %c", &yesNo);`

Comment: Still the same result. What do you mean with "that too it is const"?

Comment: You would have a buffer overflow in these lines `const char name[] = {""};

    printf("please enter a name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);` were it not for the fact that name is const and hence should not be modified at all. I would start with fixing these bugs first and **then** worry about the program not working as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying but I have absolutely no clue how.. Im new to c and my prof says we have to use const char (or did I listened wrong?). At least he says the parameter list has to have const char

Comment: Further to what @TanveerBadar wrote, your compiler should have warned you about that first line of code. Don't ignore the compiler warnings but instead fix them all up. If your compiler did not warn you then you need to turn up the warning level.

Comment: My compiler didnt warned me at all about anything (I am using cc). And I cant change the warning level because it is not my system (system of the university)

Comment: It makes sense for the functions to have `const char` parameters because that tells us that they won't change the buffer you pass in. But it does not make sense for your code to use `const char` because you obviously do need to change the buffer. Anyway, that's not the main problem. The main problem is that your `name` buffer has only declared with 1 byte of memory.

Comment: So instead of using `const char name[] ` I should have used `char name[] ` ?

Comment: As a starting point, but you should allocate a large enough character array even then to avoid the buffer overflow risk and specify how many characters you can safely read using `scanf()` format string. Also, please read documentation about input/output in `C` before jumping right ahead into writing a program. Lastly, comments are ill-suited for longer discussions. You should either read a very good book on C or take this entire conversation to a chat room.

Comment: I've already read some documentations abouf input/output in 'C' and I think I'm fine with that. But I was confused using a `const char`.

First solution: Change `const char name[]` to `char name[100]` and the first bug with scanf only taking 4 characters will go. Now I only have to fix the while loop..

Comment: '" And I cant change the warning level because it is not my system (system of the university)" --> Compile your code with an on-line computer with its warnings fully enabled.  Then compile same code on your restrictive compiler.

Comment: I've already did. There are NO errors. As mentioned before, I've fixed the bug with scanf only taking 4 characters. My current problem is the while loop and the switch case (see "AUTOMATIC/ BUG"). I write an "y" and the while loop automaticly says "0".

Comment: Yep. It works now. Thank you guys. Posted an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is a possible answer:

"Change `const char name[]` to `char name[100]`" (from @kaylum)

"Change `scanf("%c", &searchingCharacter) --> scanf(" %c", %searchingCharacters)` to consume new line in input stream" (from @user3121023)

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int searchCharacters(const char*, char);
int getLength(const char*);

int main() {

    char yesNo;
    int end = 0;
    char name[100]; <-- Changed -->

    printf("please enter a name: ");
    scanf("%99s", name);
    fflush(stdin);
    int length = getLength(name);
    printf("\n%s has a length of %i", name, length);

    while(end != 1) {
        printf("\n\nWould you like to search a character in %s (y / n)?", name);
        scanf("%c", &yesNo); <-- Changed -->

        switch(yesNo) {
            case 'y':
                printf("\nPlease enter a character: ");
                char searchingCharacter;
                scanf(" %c", &searchingCharacter); <-- Changed -->
                int numberOfCharacters = searchCharacter(name, searchingCharacter);
                printf("\nThe letter %c is %i-times", searchingCharacter, 
                numberOfCharacters);
                break;
            case 'n':
                printf("\nGood bye!");
                end++;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int searchCharacter(const char s[], char c) {
    int numberOfIterations = getLength(s);
    int numberOfCharacters = 0;
    int i;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) {
        if (s[i] == c) {
            numberOfCharacters++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfCharacters;
}

int getLength(const char s[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i++]);

    return (i - 1);
}
```

```
Input/Output:
    please enter a name: abcdefg

    abcdefg has a length of 7 characters. <-- Working/Changed -->

    Would you like to search a character in abcd (y / n)? y

    Please enter a character: a <-- Working/Changed -->

    The letter a is 1-times. <-- Working/Changed -->

    Would you like to search a character in abcdefg (y / n)? n

    Good bye!
```